# Generate variations with repetitions Erlang

Tags: erlang

I've found a way to generate the combinations of a list, but here order doesn't matter, but I need to generate variations where order matters.

Combination:

```
comb_rep(0,_) ->
    [[]];
comb_rep(_,[]) ->
    [];
comb_rep(N,[H|T]=S) ->
    [[H|L] || L <- comb_rep(N-1,S)]++comb_rep(N,T).
```

Output of this:

```
comb_rep(2,[1,2,3]).
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[2,3],[3,3]]
```

Desired output:

```
comb_rep(2,[1,2,3]).
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
```

Comment: The difference between the _output of this_ and the _desired output_ is not _order_, it’s just the fact that in the original one, combinations where the first one is bigger than the second one are omitted.

Comment: It would also be nice to know what should happen with the first argument to comb_rep is 3 (i.e. what’s the expected result of comb_rep(3, [1,2,3]), for instance).

Comment: For comb_rep(3, [1,2,3]). the result would be the permutations of the given list.
So: [1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1]

Comment: So basically, for comb_rep(K, List). I would like to get all the K length permutations of elements the elements of List. Sorry if I used the wrong words

Comment: But if that’s so, the expected result for comb_Rep(2, [1,2,3]) should not include [1,1] or [2,2] or [3,3]. Right?
Looks to me like the expected result should be
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2]].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following what’s explained in the comments, this will be my initial approach:

```
cr(0, _) ->
    [];
cr(1, L) ->
    [ [H] || H <- L ];
cr(N, L) ->
    [ [H | T] || H <- L, T <- cr(N - 1, L -- [H]) ].
```

Permutations of length 0 is an edge case. I would even consider the removal of that clause so that the function fails if invoked as such.

Permutations of length 1 means just means *each element in its own list*.

Then, for the recursive case, if you already have the permutations of the list *without* the current element (`cr(N - 1, L -- [H])`) you can just add that element to the head of each list and you just need to do that for each element in the original list (`H <- L`).

Hope this helps.